# How can achieve this permalink perfectly? domain.com/%category%/%post-name%

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want to make a custom post URL like `domain.com/%category%/%post-name%` and I am able to do it but the problem is, the pages, posts showing 404.

I registered a custom post named `download` with `array('slug' => '%download_category%', 'with_front' => false);`

there is `download_category` associated with `download` post type.

This is the rewrite rule `add_rewrite_rule( '^/(.*)/(.*)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=download&name=$matches[2]', 'top' );`

And post link set correctly.
[image]

It is working fine. But the problem is, other pages show me 404. below is the screenshot with Query monitor request.
[image]

How can I solve it? Any help is appreciated.